# How to access custom classes into main classes using objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to create single `tableview` with `parent` and `child` `accordion cells`. For this accordion cells I have create two cells into single `tableview storyboard` and gave separate `Identifier` and classes  for two cells and doing some logics into below method. Now the problem is I Need to access the custom cell class and I have connected `outlets` cell `storyboard UI` to custom classes but I cant access that UI into below method.

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        //cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:1];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"parentCell"];

    }
    NSDictionary *dicForIndex = [self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    if ([[dicForIndex valueForKey:@"isChild"] boolValue] == YES) {

        //cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"childCell"];

        UILabel *labelName = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
        labelName.text = [dicForIndex valueForKey:@"name"];

    }else{

        UILabel *labelName = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
        labelName.text = [dicForIndex valueForKey:@"name"];

    }
    [cell setIndentationLevel:[[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"level"] intValue]];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to access? "cell"? What is the class name of "cell"?

Comment: actually I have create two cells into tableview storyboard with two custom classes above mentioned code I am using but the plm I cant access the custom class outlet UI inside above method@anthu

Comment: "two custom classes". What is it named?

Comment: parenttableviewCell and childtableviewcell. @anthu

Comment: u should check for child cell first before set it as parent cell, i saw u set all cell as parent cell first then u only check...

Comment: You should use e.g: `parenttableviewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

Comment: @anhtu If I use like above how can i put return for both If I put return inside the condition Its taking first Identifier only. Could ypu please modify my above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"parentCell"];
        parenttableviewCell *cellParent = (parenttableviewCell *)cell;
        // custom  something ...
        cellParent.labelA.text = @"A"; 
    }
    ... 
    if ...
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"childCell"];
        childtableviewCell *cellchild = (childtableviewCell *)cell;
        // custom  something ...
    }

return cell;
```